# KivyMD ElementCard doesn't display set text, image and subtext

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

As a first KivyMD "Hello-world" I wanted to simply run the code of the following repo:

https://github.com/HusamFathi/KivyMD-Dashboard-UI

But instead of this:
[How the app should look like, after execution.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7arbk.png)

the app, after compilation, looks like this:

[How the compiled app looks on my computer.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfZjL.png)

I installed Kivy and KivyMD via the respective pip-commands and thus now have Kivy 2.1.0 and KivyMD 1.1.1 installed in the venv of this project.

My OS is Ubuntu 22.04.

I expected the app to look exactly like the picture shown in the repo of the code.

Is there something wrong with my installation?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I used:

`from kivymd.uix.card import MDCard`